# D3 date parse issue with timezone offset

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js

i am creating a line chart which have x-axis as time scale axis and i have to parse the date data coming from backed.

The date is coming in this format from the backend -> `2016-01-14T02:55:55.000Z`

I wrote this parse function using d3 date format

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L");
```

But this piece of code not able to parse the above mentioned date format and i have to remove `Z` from the x-axis date data which is takes time when there are huge number of data points.

So, is there a way to handle the above mentioned date format in d3?

Comment: Is the date a typeof string or a Date object?

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis: It is a string.

Comment: how are you calling parseDate?  parseDate( new Date( '2016-01-14T02:55:55.000Z' ) )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `Z` in the format string:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");
```

I would recommend using `var parseDate = d3.time.format.iso;` instead, as this is [more forgiving](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#format_iso).

Comment: Thank You for the answer. This `var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");` solves my issue.